# Shouldn’t Bind() pass child control’s values to GridView before Page.PreRender?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview, viewstate

> For controls such as the GridView, DetailsView, and FormView controls, data-binding expressions are resolved automatically during the control's PreRender event

But doesn’t data source control perform updates prior to Page.PreRender event? Meaning, shouldn’t Bind() pass  child control’s values to GridView ( so they can be passed to data source control as parameters ) before data source control updates the data source, thus before Page.PreRender event?

thanx

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

[ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx#data_binding_events_for_databound_controls)